# DB2 Import with pipe delimeter and codebase is japanese script

Tags: import, db2, codebase

I m using following import command for importing japanese script into db2 table.

*Import from './data/product attributes to be uploaded_20120124.txt' of del modified by coldel| CODEPAGE=932 INSERT INTO TEMP_UPLOAD_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES (ProductGuid,CATEGORY_GUID,LOCALEGUID,REALMGUID,CATCHING_PHRASE,GENERIC_NAME,INGREDIENTS,QUANTITY,DOSE,NUTIRITION_FACTS,PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,RECOMMENDED_FOR,PROMOTION_MSG,MESSAGE)*

I get the message as:

SQL3017N  A delimiter is not valid or is used more than once.

When checking the message code definition, it seems pipe may not be valid delimeter.
It also says: For UTF-8 data, the valid range for the delimiters is 0x00 - 0x7F inclusive

Where do I find the mapping of the hex and symbol? what are the valid delimetrs in this case?
or is there any other issue?

Please advice.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input data is properly delimited, you should be able to import a pipe-delimited file by specifying `COLDEL0x7C` as a modifier for the IMPORT command.

Comment: I tried it : Import from './data/product attributes to be uploaded_20120124.txt' of del modified by COLDEL0x7C CODEPAGE=932 INSERT INTO TEMP_UPLOAD_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES (ProductGuid,CATEGORY_GUID,LOCALEGUID,REALMGUID,CATCHING_PHRASE,GENERIC_NAME,INGREDIENTS,QUANTITY,DOSE,NUTIRITION_FACTS,PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,RECOMMENDED_FOR,PROMOTION_MSG,MESSAGE)
SQL3109N  The utility is beginning to load data from file "./data/product
attributes to be uploaded_20120124.txt".

SQL3017N  A delimiter is not valid or is used more than once.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after changing delimeter to TAB
Japanese codepages only allow delimiters in the range 0x00 to 0x3F, 
| is 0x7C
tab is 0x09